# does caching values of SharedPreferences make sense?

Tags: android, performance, preferences

In my current Android app I have several settings stored in SharedPreferences and one object which handles access to them. I now wonder if it makes sense to cache the values or if doesn't mater much accessing them like:

```
public final boolean isxxxEnabled() {
    return preferences.getBoolean("xxx", false);
}
```

instead of

```
public final boolean isxxxEnabled() {
            // check if value changed
            // if not, check if value is cached
            // decide whether to return cached or new
            // cache value
    return 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caching shared preferences isn't really necessary. The speed up you're gonna get will be marginal at best and it's going to increase the code you have to write. I'd say don't bother.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: Okay, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684174/3124150)'s a reference.